# Android studio doesn't show flutter project structure

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I was playing around Android Studio and don't remember what i changed, i am not able to switch my project back to flutter structure. I can open it in Visual Studio code correctly but in Android studio, it always open like below and i am unable to find option to revert back what i did.

[image]

When i click on project tab.
[image]

Comment: What happens when you click on the Project tab?

Comment: Just added screenshot of project tab.

Comment: Ok, I played around with my AS. There is an option to remove it from the sidebar, but opening it then reverts it to appear in the toolbar. Try selecting the options and using the move to option to "move to" the left hand bottom. It may have been moved to a toolbar you have hidden.

Comment: Try removing the project reference, then on the home screen for Android Studio click on Open Project and navigate to your project again and reopen it with the project folder as the root folder.

Comment: I already tried that option. But still same...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the solution that worked for me was to cilk on the project button
[image]

Then select android (in my case) and switch it for project folder

[image]